# Powershell v2.0 Foreach loop failing when run on PS v4

Tags: powershell, foreach, powershell-4.0

Hi is there a difference in the way that PS v4 (running from a 2012 server) reacts to a Foreach loop written in V2?

I have this simple script that works in v2 but produces an error on v4:

```
$Serverlist = Import-CSV "D:\PendingReboot\AllADServers.csv"
    Foreach ($Computer.Name in $Serverlist)
    {      
          $ADComputer = $Computer.Name
          $ADOwner = $Computer.Description
          If (!($Computer.Description))
          {$ADOwner = "Unassigned"}
          $ADOU = $AD | select DistinguishedName 
          "$ADComputer $ADOwner"
    }

Server1 Team1
Server2 Team2
etc. etc.
```

The Error in V4 is:

```
At D:\PendingReboot\Test.ps1:2 char:23
+     Foreach ($Computer.Name in $Serverlist)
+                       ~
Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.
At D:\PendingReboot\Test.ps1:2 char:43
+     Foreach ($Computer.Name in $Serverlist)
+                                           ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingInInForeach
```

Comment: `$Computer.Name in $Serverlist` -> `$Computer in $Serverlist`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the AllADServers.csv file has more than one column: Name, Description, OU. Does this help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PetSerAl's comment is correct. You should be using `foreach ($Computer in $ServerList)`. As for why it works in PowerShell v2 and not in v4, well I can only assume that they corrected the behavior, as it should have failed in v2.

Basically your `.Name` in that portion is doing nothing, as evidenced by the fact that you still needed to specify `.Name` on the very first line within the loop.

Essentially, this was a syntax error that wasn't caught in an earlier version.